# Solve for div F. Vector calculus divergence and curl

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

$r = xi + yj + zk$

$s = ||r||$

$$F=\frac{r}{s^p}$$

Solve div F. The answer in the textbook is $\frac{3-p}{s^p}$.

My work so far:

div $F = \nabla\cdot F$

$F=\frac{xi+yj+zk}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \ )^p}$

Show me the solution. I need help with the gradient (partial derivatives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first component of $\nabla \cdot F$ is

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2}}=$$
$$=\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2}-px^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2-1}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^p}=$$
$$=\frac{1-px^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2}}.$$

The second one is

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\frac{1-py^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2}}.$$

And the third one is

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=\frac{1-pz^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac p2}}.$$

The sum of these components is, indeed

$$\frac{3-p}{s^p}.$$